# Laravel 5.4 Javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I've got a problem with my Laravel site.
It doesn't load any JS. The Collapse of my navbar and the auto-scroll function don't work at all. It's like it doesn't load the JS at all. But I don't get any errors and the hyperlinks are fine. I can load the files in my Browser without any problem. Only the functionality doesn't work.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      @include('layouts.nav')
    </nav>
```

the Navbar file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
      <span class="sr-only">Navigation ein-/ausblenden</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dr. Geiger</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#header">Welcome</a></li>
      <li><a href="#welcome">Öffnungszeiten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#schwerpunkte">Unsere Schwerpunkte</a></li>
      <li><a href="#unserepraxis">Unsere Arztpraxis</a></li>
      <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#impressum">Impressum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the smoothscroll.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add scrollspy to <body>
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: ".navbar",
    offset: 50
  });

  // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
  $("#navbar-collapse-main a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you including your smoothscroll.js anywhere?

Comment: <!-- Das neueste kompilierte und minimierte JavaScript -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js') !!}"></script>
      <!-- Jquery 3.2.1 -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') !!}"></script>
      <!-- Smooth Scroll für OnePage -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/smoothscroll.js') !!}"></script>

Comment: So yeah and its reachable in my quellcode

Comment: Don't you have put it inside `<script>` tags ?

Comment: In that case, bring up a developer console in your browser to verify that it's loading the smoothscroll.js in the network tab, and see if there are any errors in the console tab.

Comment: Bootstrap cant reach the jquery file... But its in the same directory :O

Comment: If i do use the web-hyperlinks its working. Just not with the files.

Comment: It was about the {!! !!} tags... If im using {{asset....}} its working fine